# Pointer to struct inside a struct; How to access without errors?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

As far as I know, if the item inside a structure is a pointer, you call it with `->`, if it's a normal value it is used `.`.

here my typedefs:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int quantity;
}ing;

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    ing *n;
    int price, n_ing, max_producity;
}prod;
```

then I declare a `prod a;` and I allocate `a->n=malloc(n*sizeof(ing));`. 
But when I try to access to `a.n->name` it gives me error.

All the 4 combinations gives me error "error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'prod' (or 'ing'))" or "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector".

Why?

---

```
    int ret_max_producity(prod a, ing n, int dim_n)
    {
        int max_prod=32100, i;
        for(i=0; i<a.n_ing; i++)
        {
/* here!->*/if((n[find_ing(n, a.n[i]->name, dim_n)].quantity)/(a.n->quantity)<max_prod)
            {
/* here!->*/    max_prod=(n[find_ing(n ,a.n[i]->name, dim_n)].quantity/a.n->quantity);
            }
        }
        if(max_prod==32100)
        {
            printf("ERROR WHILE FINDING MAX PRODUCITY FOR PRODUCT %s, ABORTING", a.name);
            system("pause");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return max_prod;
    }
```

---

```
int find_ing(ing v, char *s, int dim)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(s, v.name)==0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nERROR WHILE FINDING INGREDIENT %s IN VECTOR, ABORTING...", s);
    system("pause");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

[image: The errors]

Comment: It would be worth reading a tutorial on C operators, this is most certainly covered in any beginner-level language tutorial.

Comment: It's not that if the item INSIDE the structure is a pointer that you use `->` it's when the symbol ITSELF is a pointer variable that you use '->'  When the symbol is of the type struct foo then you use a '.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`As far as I know, if the item inside a structure is a pointer, you call it with ->, if it's a normal value it is used ..`

No, the `.` operator is used to access the members of a structure, the `->` operator is a short cut for dereference and `.`, so you use that if you have a pointer to your structure. So:

```
ing *n = malloc(sizeof(ing));

n->quantity = 5;   // This is the same as 
(*n).quantity = 5; // this.
```

---

In the most basic sense, to access a structure's members you do this:

```
ing n;
n.quanity = 5;
```

To access the structure's members if you declare a pointer to your structure, you do this:

```
ing *n;
n = malloc(sizeof(ing));
n->quanity = 5;
```

---

`"prod a; and I allocate a->n=malloc(n*sizeof(ing));. But when I try to access to a->n->name it gives me error"`

If you are declaring a structure like that, then the reason it's giving you an error is because you're trying to deference something that's not a pointer.

```
a.n->name
```

would be correct.

**EDIT**
After seeing your code I see what your problem is:

```
* here!->*/if((n[find_ing(n, a.n[i]->name, dim_n)].quantity)/(a.n->quantity)<max_prod)
```

The issue is you're doing more dereferencing than you think. The `[i]` is doing an add and dereference then the `->` is doing another level of it.

Here's a quick example of how it should look:

```
prod a;
a.n = malloc(3 * sizeof(ing));  // array of 3 ing structs
a.n[1].quantity = 5;            // access quanity member of ing struct 1
```

**EDIT 2**
Here's the line in question:

```
* here!->*/if((n[find_ing(n, a.n[i]->name, dim_n)].quantity)/(a.n->quantity)<max_prod)
```

Here's what it should have been:

```
if((n[find_ing(n, a.n[i].name, dim_n)].quantity)/(a.n->quantity)<max_prod)
```

**EDIT 3**
Totally overlooked the obvious. You're passing a single `ing` struct to this function called `n`:

```
int ret_max_producity(prod a, ing n, int dim_n)
                                ^
                                | 
                         that's just a single struct totally different than
                       the n that's passed in as a member in the `a` struct
```

But then in your if check you're trying to access this struct as an array:

```
n[find_ing(n, a.n[i]->name, dim_n)].quantity
```

You **do not** have an array of `ing` structures in the `n` variable, you only have a single `ing` variable. So it's yelling at you for treating this single struct as an array of structs.

Comment: [here](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/3233/catturadischermata6.png) you can see what I'm talking about... i don't know what to do. Every combination gives me an error (Edit: one image is a duplicated, but still gives me error)....

Comment: @LambertoBasti - er.. no, you didn't do every combination, you missed the one that works. ;)  See EDIT2 in my answer.  You have to do `a.n[i].name` because you're using the `[]` subscript, but you use `a.n->quanity` because there's no `[]` subscript there. Got it?

Comment: I owe you a pizza for the patience :) by the way, it still give me [error](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/4381/catturadischermata7.png)

Comment: @LambertoBasti - OK, I missed the most obvious thing about your code. See edit 3. The problem is that you don't have an array there, you passed a single structure `n` of type `ing` to your function and you're trying to access it with the `[]` like it was an array. You **have** and array named `n` in the `a` variable, but the `n` you passed into the function is different and is not an array. :) May I suggest some more descriptive names for your variables? It might have helped to find this faster.

Comment: Finally is solved! Really thank you! My bad, I'm programming since 10 AM switching beetwin C and assembly! I need a pause :)

Comment: @LambertoBasti - You can pause and get me that pizza you owe me. ;) Happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

If you declare a prod a, and not a prod * a, then you need to access the members by a.n.  Since n is a pointer, it should be a.n->name.

-> is only used if you have a pointer to a structure.  . is used when you have an instance of a structure.

prod a;

a.n = malloc(sizeof(ing *));  //Why are you multiplying this number by n?  don't do that.
a.n = address of instance of ing that you made. a.n = &ing structure.

a.n->whatever = Now you can access This value

Edit:

Get rid of the type defs.  It should read

```
struct Foo{

members
};

struct Foo2{
members
};
```

Then it should be fine.  You're using typedef in the wrong way I believe.

```
struct ing
{
    char name[50];
    int quantity;
};

struct prod
{
    char name[50];
    ing *n;
    int price, n_ing, max_producity;
};
```

You also need to pass int he addresses of both of those structs, and then get a pointer out of them.  So your function declaration should read:

```
int ret_max_producity(prod * a, ing  *n, int dim_n)
```

and when calling ret_max_productivity, it shoudl have:

```
ret_max_productivity(&a, &n, int dim_n);
```

Comment: yeah, it still gives me error....

Comment: i need a vector of ing inside prod, otherwise i would have choose to declare it normally! 
I'm afraid it still gives me error! I'll link the function I'm working on

Comment: @LambertoBasti - I see your problem, noted it in my answer below. By the way, in C it's not called a vector, it's called an array.